# SwiftUI - Display selected value with Single Selected

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want when I finish selecting the language and click the Save button it will return the ContentView page and display the language I have selected. And when I click again, it has to checkmark the language I selected before.

I have successfully displayed the data, but I don't know how to save it when I click the Save button

Here is all my code currently

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination:LanguageView() ) {
                    Text("Language")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("I want to show the language here ")
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

LanguageView

```
struct LanguageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomLanguageView()
            
            Button(action: {
            })
            {
                Text("Save")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct CustomLanguageView: View {
    var language = ["US", "English", "Mexico", "Canada"]
    @State var selectedLanguage: String? = nil
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(language, id: \.self) { item in
                SelectionCell(language: item, selectedLanguage: self.$selectedLanguage)
                    .padding(.trailing,40)
                Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame( height: 1,alignment: .bottom)
            }
            .frame(height:15)
        }
    }
}

struct SelectionCell: View {
    let language: String
    @Binding var selectedLanguage: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(language)
            Spacer()
            if language == selectedLanguage {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width:20, height: 15)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.selectedLanguage = self.language
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  What is not working with your code and what have you tried to do to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to deal with Button. You can copy my code to run

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to "Save" something but if you are just trying to get it back to the other view you could do something like this that I quickly setup.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var language: String? = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination:LanguageView(language: $language)) {
                    Text("Language")
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                    Text(language!)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct LanguageView: View {
    
    @Binding var language: String?
    @State var selectedLanguage: String? = ""
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            CustomLanguageView(selectedLanguage: $selectedLanguage)
            
            Button(action: {
                language = selectedLanguage
            })
            {
                Text("Save")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct CustomLanguageView: View {
    var language = ["US", "English", "Mexico", "Canada"]
    @Binding var selectedLanguage: String?
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(language, id: \.self) { item in
                SelectionCell(language: item, selectedLanguage: self.$selectedLanguage)
                    .padding(.trailing,40)
                Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame( height: 1,alignment: .bottom)
            }
            .frame(height:15)
        }
    }
}

struct SelectionCell: View {
    let language: String
    @Binding var selectedLanguage: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(language)
            Spacer()
            if language == selectedLanguage {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width:20, height: 15)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.selectedLanguage = self.language
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you are actually trying to save it to the device for later use you could use

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(selectedLanguage, forKey: "language")
```

Then to Retrieve it later do

```
UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "language") as! String
```

Comment: Can you edit it according to my structure ?

Comment: Ok there you go. I just found it kind of weird to have 4 views for a small thing like selecting a language.

Comment: i followed you, but when i press it again it doesn't show the language i selected before.